# Publishing All Project Files in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net

Is there a security risk associated with using the option that copies "All project files" when publishing a web application into a production environment? I normally use the option "Only files needed to run this application" which does not copy the source code to the server.

I am the only person with access to the production server. There is also no issue with cluttering the production server as there isn't much on it. In fact I don't mind having all the source files be kept on the server together with the binaries.

Is there any security issue with this?

Comment: Is there anything to gain by doing it?

Comment: Nothing could be gained in terms of the code functionality, obviously. I am just wondering if there is a security risk in case one wants to keep the code together with the binaries on the production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no one can get access to the production server then there is no security risk with this option. However this is a pretty big if! I can’t see any real benefit from using the **All project files** or **All files in the source project folder** options – these don’t even allow you to update the web application in place on the production server which might be useful in some situations. I would stick to the **Only files needed to run this application** option just to be save.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, like you said, the whole application has to be published each time (can't just change files like a the ASP.NET 2.0 Website projects). I like the idea of having the source code on the server also act as backups in case my other backups fail :)